# How do I run a bash command and process its output in a resque worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, resque, ruby-1.9.3

I have a resque worker that stops all processing as soon as it has run a bash command. Here is my worker:

```
class ProductJsonSaver
  @queue = :products

  def self.perform(id)
    product = Product.find(id)
    json = `phantomjs #{Rails.root}/lib/product_scrape.js`
    product_json = JSON.parse(json)
    p "Procesing is done"
    p "Product JSON: #{product_json}"
    product.update_attributes({:processed => true})
  end
end
```

If I run

```
Resque.enqueue(ProductJsonSaver, 1)
```

I can see the worker run the bash command, I see the bash command's output but dont see the print statements afterwards not does the product's processed attribute update. resque-web does not show the process as failed either. In fact, simply running `ProductJsonSaver.perform(1)` from the rails console works.

Is this a bug with Resque?

Nuts & Bolts: Rails 3.2.11, OSX, ruby-1.9.3, resque 1.23.0

**EDITED** code to make problem clearer.

Comment: is there a reason that you are not actually using "json" variable?  I see you are passing "prod" to your #save_from_json

Comment: Updated the code, basically nothing after the command within `` runs.

Answer (score 1):

Is that original code actually saving the data or just properly puts-ing your "Processing is done" string?

Your line:

```
json = `cat #{Rails.root}/data/#{id}.json`
```

Isn't actually doing anything. As in the last line you're just passing it the Product you fetched in the first line. Also why are you setting a variable in the last line instead of allowing the natural return from the class method that you're calling on Product.

Also you should read the file like so...

```
# in top of class 
require 'file' 

# in resque process method
File.open("#{Rails.root}/data/#{@id}.json", 'r') {|f| f.read}
```

Or automatically parse it into a JSON object by wrapping that in

```
 # in top of class 
 require 'json'  
 # in resque process method
 JSON.parse(File.open("#{Rails.root}/data/#{@id}.json", 'r') {|f| f.read})
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Appreciate the detailed answer, but the cat command was just an example. Basically need a way to consume stdout from a bash command and use that in my worker.

Comment: how is "your stdout" different from reading a file from Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the false alarm. Maybe this helps someone else. I had older resque workers that did not exit but had an older code base running. So every time I would queue a job, an older worker would accept and run.

> $ ps -ef | grep [r]esque

and kill -9 to the rescue!